# Get bindingConfiguration name of endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Suppose an endpoint is configured like this:

```
<endpoint name="endPointName" 
    address="net.tcp://localhost:2082/Service.svc" 
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sessionFullBinding"
    contract="Contract" />
```

How could we get `sessionFullBinding` of `bindingConfiguration` if we try `Endpoint.Binding.Name` it will return `NetTcpBinding` not `sessionFullBinding`.

I am looking to get the `bindingConfiguration` name of `EndPoint`.

Comment: I don't think you can do this - after all, the "binding configuration" is only designed to apply certain settings to your binding...... those settings will be applied to your `.Binding` object, but the *name* of the binding configuration isn't stored anywhere, and therefore not accessible at runtime, I believe

Comment: Thanks for comment, I think so.